# How to create application for Motorola mc70 device?

Tags: c#, sql, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

i am new bee in this field. i have a motorola mc70 device.i want to create an application for it in which device scans barcode and than put data of barcode into my sql server database. i have worked in visual  studio 2010. now i have a motorola scanner sdk and user guide. but i don't know how to create application for these types of devices. 
i have worked in c# so i am familiar with it and i am using sql server database for it.
i don't know where to start?? should i make console application or other type of application.
Can anyone help to sort this out and provide procedure to create application for this device...
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're gonna to use .net then you have to get Visual Studio 2008 and download the Windows Mobile SDK. They removed the support for creating Windows Mobile applications in VS 2010 and up.

In Visual Studio 2008 you will find smart device project etc.. And there is also a Emulator for it.

There is other options to create applications for these devices. Like RhoMobile Suite. With it you code HTML5 / CSS3/ Javascript / Ruby etcc. But it is not free.
Developing applications in RhoMobile is free but when deploying it and uses some features will cost.

Comment: Can u please explain more about samrt devices in visual studio 2008. As i have worked on it for some time so i think i can work on it. But i don't know how to start with smart device for these kind of application. i didn't see anything about scanners in it.

Comment: @user3346501 you have to download a SDK for the scanner I think the name was datawedge google for it.

Comment: @user3346501 with datawedge installed on the device you can use the scanner. It will work like a keyboard. When you scan something it will type it in. So you can make a Textbox and set focus on it then scan somehting it will fill the textbox with the code. Or you can config the datawedge to behave like a serialport/com port. Then in c# you have to listen to that port and get the data out of it.

Comment: i googled it before and installed it into my device also. but i can't understand about it. i just want to make application that can save data to my online database. More confusing thing is that i created console application fot it and it runs only in visual studio when i connect it with my scanner through cable. i am totally stucked which way i should go. Sort it out man if u created these type of application before.... Thanks in Advance..

Comment: @user3346501 Open notes in you handheld and try to scan something does it work ?